# Create new formatted column in Pandas using another column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following data set in a pandas dataframe:

```
I219
F03
C449
C189
```

I need to create a new column where if the length of the cell is 4, then it needs to have a period after the third character like this:

```
I21.9
F03
C44.9
C18.9
```

After digging around StackOverflow, I came up with this lambda expression, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df.UNDERLYINGCAUSE.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 4 else x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:])
```

The error I am getting is 'object type 'float' as no len()'. Not sure where this is coming from since I do not have any float values in this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your lambda function is doing exactly the opposite of what you wanted because the formatting was not right. Also, you can convert the column `dtype` to object with `astype(str)`. Try this:

```
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df.UNDERLYINGCAUSE.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:] if len(x) == 4 else x )
```

Alternatively, since you are dealing with column/series manipulation, you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead of [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), which is faster and efficient at column manipulation.

```
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df.UNDERLYINGCAUSE.astype(str).map(lambda x: x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:] if len(x) == 4 else x )
```

**Output**:

```
  UNDERLYINGCAUSE UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST
0            I219                I21.9
1             F03                  F03
2            C449                C44.9
3            C189                C18.9
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out my ID10T error with my answer, but I'll give yours a shot as well.

Comment: Sure, love to know if it works for you. Just as a suggestion, working with `map` always better if just want to manipulate one column.

Comment: Just tried your answer, and it works as well. I'll have to remember the map tip though for the future. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps. Would be nice if you can upvote the answer. So, that people see it  that works.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out my error. I needed to put my x in str() for my if statement.

```
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df.UNDERLYINGCAUSE.apply(lambda x: x if len(str(x)) < 4 else x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:])
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that ternary operator results should be vice versa. To make sure that column type is string, you can change it before applying lambda:

```
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'].astype(str)
df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'] = df['UNDERLYINGCAUSE_TEST'].apply(lambda x: x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:] if len(x) == 4 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer is correct, but here are alternatives. For future reference, you can access strings in `Series` with `Series.str` method

```
df = {'c':['I219','F03','C449','C189']}
df['new_c'] = df.c.str[:3] + '.' + df.c.str[3:]
df.loc[df['new_c'].isna(), 'new_c'] = df.loc[df['new_c'].isna(), 'c']

df['new_c2'] = df.c.apply(lambda x: x if len(x) < 4 else x[0:3] + '.' + x[3:])
```